# JS substring text replace with <span> recursive

Tags: javascript, recursion, replace, substring, highlight

I have a string "Hello, this is a text string."

And I have an array

```
[{start: 0, length: 5, color: "red"}, {start: 3, length: 5, color: "yellow"}]
```

I am trying to figure out how to replace these values with  elements with classes. Originally, I just did a recursive substring starting from end to beginning. But, elements can overlap, causing counting issues. Obviously only one color could show at a time, but I'd still like the code to be able to execute, even if a user wants to highlight two of the same spots.

Is there any way to do this easily?

Comment: You could create an array of properties for every letter `[ { a: [ 'red' ] }, b : [ 'yellow'] } ]` . Then, you could rebuild a text with HTML tags included.

Comment: Wrap each letter in a span. Give the spans that fall into the ranges CSS classes (or apply styles directly).

Comment: "elements can overlap". How? You should show your expected output because this doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can check every letter what colors it should be assigned to and then you can build your HTML structure out of it. (The following example has not been tested intensively; do your own tests before using in production.)

```js
var string = "Hello, this is a text string.";
var requirements = [
   {start: 0, length: 5, color: "red"},
   {start: 3, length: 5, color: "yellow"},
   {start: 0, length: 10, color: "blue"},
   {start: 9, length: 15, color: "green"}
];
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  result[i] = {
    letter: string[i],
    colors: []
  };
  for(var j = 0; j < requirements.length; j++) {
    if(i === requirements[j].start || (i > requirements[j].start && i < requirements[j].start + requirements[j].length)) {
      result[i].colors.push(requirements[j].color);
    }
  }
}

var output = "";
var isColoring = false;
for(var l = 0; l < result.length; l++) {
  if(result[l].colors.length) {
    if(!isColoring || (result[l-1] && result[l-1].colors[0] && result[l-1].colors[0] !== result[l].colors[0])) {
      output += '<span class="' + result[l].colors[0] + '">';
      isColoring = true;
    }
  } else {
    isColoring = false;
  }
  output += result[l].letter;
  if(result[l].colors.length) {
    if(isColoring && !(result[l+1] && result[l+1].colors[0] && result[l+1].colors[0] === result[l].colors[0])) {
      output += '</span>';
      isColoring = false;
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector('.text-wrapper').innerHTML = output;
document.querySelector('.requirements').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(requirements, null, 3);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
.yellow { color: yellow; }
.blue { color: blue; }
.green { color: green; }
```

```html
<pre class="text-wrapper"></pre>
<pre class="requirements"></pre>
```